# toggle() not working with li

Tags: jquery

Hello freinds i want to toggle `<li>` but its not working i have tried following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){          
    $('#fly').hide();
    $('li').click(function(){
        $("#fly").hide(500);
        $(this).siblings("#fly").toggle(500);
    })
})
</script>
```

html

```
<ul >
  <li>hi
  <div id="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div id="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div id="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div id="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me out

Comment: an ID needs to be unique. change your IDs or make them classes.

Comment: Also, `$(this).siblings("#fly")` should be `$(this).children("#fly")`

Comment: Although javascript will automatically place semicolons (line terminators), you should not omit them. It will someday cause you problems.

Comment: @alpacalips thats why I added them back in :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite your bad IDs this, I think, is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fly').hide();
  $('li').click(function(){
    $(this).hide(500);
    $(this).siblings().show(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: you might consider using "[id='fly']" selector, for most browser will return only one element if getElementById is called, which is the case for the "#" selector

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/W2Jw9/)

```
$('.fly').hide();
$('li').click(function() {
    $('.fly', this).toggle(500);
    $(this).siblings().find('.fly').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul >
    <li>hi
        <div class="fly">i m here</div>
    </li>
    <li>hi
        <div class="fly">i m here</div>
    </li>
    <li>hi
        <div class="fly">i m here</div>
    </li>
    <li>hi
        <div class="fly">i m here</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.fly').hide();

$('li').click(function(){

     $(".fly").hide(500);
     $(this).siblings(".fly").toggle(500);
})
})

</script>
```

html

```
<ul >
  <li>hi
  <div class="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div class="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div class="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
   <li>hi
  <div class="fly">i m here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```